# Symfony2 Command results to File size limit exceeded

Tags: php, symfony, assetic, clear-cache

I am working on a Symfony2 project. I have built few bundles already and have been developing on the "dev" environment through app_dev.php

Now, I feel like I am ready to put this on the prod environment. So I ran this command in the command line:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

But all I got as a response is this:

> File size limit exceeded

When I looked at the usage of the server, it's only at 19%. So I still a lot of space to work with.

What other configuration have I not yet checked? I have been at it with this problem for quite some time now. Searched around the web and all they got are from `php.ini`. And I already played around with it and the same result is still displaying

How can I resolve this? Please help.

Comment: usually php.ini of php cli is different from php.ini of your webserver. Could you confirm that the file you played around is the same file with `php -r 'phpinfo();'|grep 'php.ini'`?

Comment: the file I opened is /etc/php.ini and yes that is exactly what I was changing. But even before I changed it, the values are already big, I just made it bigger.

Comment: Try to clear log files. phps error_log and symfony ones in app/logs. Looks like some of log files exceeded size limit (like 2gb or more)

Comment: Holy Crap!! it worked.. Thank you very much dude.. Like I said I have at it with issue for quite some time.. Wow.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

Just to close this question, putting accepted answer from comments:

> Try to clear log files. php's error_log and symfony ones in app/logs.
>   Looks like some of log files exceeded size limit (like 2gb or more)